How to normalize the general solution of a Sturm Liouville problem?
Say for instance we have a solution to a differential equation which is a Sturm-Liouville problem
$$y(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n\Phi_n(x)+\sum_{n\geq 1}b_n\varphi_n(x)$$
with $\{\Phi_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ and $\{\varphi_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ being orthogonal autofunctions bases and they're orthogonal to each other too. In order to normalize $y(x)$ what should I do?:
Should I do
$$\begin{aligned}\hat y(x)=\dfrac{y(x)}{||y||}=\dfrac{y(x)}{\sqrt{\!\langle\, y\,|y\,\rangle}\, }&=\dfrac{y(x)}{\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{n,m\geq 1}a_na_m\langle\Phi_m(x)|\Phi_n(x)\rangle+\sum_{n,m\geq 1}b_nb_m\langle\varphi_n(x)|\varphi_m(x)\rangle} }\\
&=\dfrac{y(x)}{\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n^2\langle\Phi_n(x)|\Phi_n(x)\rangle+\sum_{n\geq 1}b_n^2\langle\varphi_n(x)|\varphi_n(x)\rangle} }\ ?\end{aligned}$$
Or maybe
$$\hat y(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n\hat \Phi_n(x)+\sum_{n\geq 1}b_n\hat \varphi_n(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n\frac{\Phi_n(x)}{\sqrt{\langle\Phi_n(x)|\Phi_n(x)\rangle}}+\sum_{n\geq 1}b_n\frac{ \varphi_n(x)}{\sqrt{\langle\varphi_n(x)|\varphi_n(x)\rangle}}?$$
In other words, analogous to algebra, should I do
$$\mathbf{\hat u}=\frac{\mathbf{u}}{||\mathbf{\hat u}||}\ \text{ or }\ \mathbf{\hat u}=a_n \mathbf{\hat v_n}+b_n\mathbf{\hat w_n}?$$

You can't have a non-trivial function that is orthogonal to a basis. That seems to contradict what you are saying about $\Phi,\varphi$
